# Swift Using an app level global constant in a library package

Tags: swift, global, swiftpm

This should be easy but its got me stuck.

In my app, I have a global constant defined as

```
public let apiKey = "hjbcsddsbsdjhksdbvbsdbvsdbvs"
```

I want to use that apiKey in a library that I have added to my project as a SwiftPackage. I need it in the library to initiate a service.

```
Library.configure(withAPIKey: apiKey)
```

but I get the error

```
Cannot find apiKey in scope
```

I have tried wrapping the apiKey into a struct like so:

```
public struct globalConstants {
    static let apiKey = "hjbcsddsbsdjhksdbvbsdbvsdbvs"
}
```

and using it as such:

```
Library.configure(withAPIKey: globalConstants.apiKey)
```

and I get a similar error message.

What am I missing?

Comment: `Library.configure(withAPIKey: apiKey)`, from where do you call this function?

Comment: For a global say `Library.configure(withAPIKey: Library.apiKey)`. For a struct both the struct and the static let must be marked public!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, this call is made in the SwiftPM Library.

Comment: @matt, the global is not in the library, it is in the app and I want to use it in the library.

Comment: But the library cannot see the app! It's the other way round.

Comment: You need to pass the value from the app to the library via the public api of the library. Or load it from file in the library if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your global constant is declared in the wrong place in the hierarchy of your app.
Making the `Library.configure(withAPIKey: apiKey)` not "see" the `apiKey`.

Although this is a SwiftUI example, that works, you can do something
similar in your particular app.

```
import SwiftUI
import OWOneCall   // <-- my SwiftPackage library 


// -- here the app "global" constant declaration
public let apiKey = "hjbcsddsbsdjhksdbvbsdbvsdbvs"

// here the app 
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

// elsewhere in my app
struct ContentView: View {
    // OWProvider is in my SwiftPackage library
    let weatherProvider = OWProvider(apiKey: apiKey) // <-- here pass the apiKey to the library
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this by having a `Constants.swift` file:

```swift
public struct Constants {
    static let apiKey = "YOUR_KEY_HERE"
}
```

Then, assuming the file you're calling the constant from *is in the same project and target* as this `Constants.swift` file, you can call it as follows:

```swift
print(Constants.apiKey) // prints "YOUR_KEY_HERE"
```

If this doesn't work, check if this new file is actually included in the project and a member of your target. That might be the issue in your case.

As a side note, be careful when adding API keys, secrets, and other sensitive information to your application's codebase. You might want to add it to your `.gitignore` file, for example.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately what I am trying to achieve is actually using the value in a library which is NOT in the same project.

Comment: I mean that the `Constants.swift` and the file you're calling the library from should be in the same project and target (otherwise the file cannot find the constants file). You should pass the `Constants.apiKey` as an argument to the library's method. What's the library you're using and the method you are trying to call?